# Entity Framework DbContext Instance DataReader already open

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I don't have much experience with Entity Framework, so I'll try to give as much information I can and try not to make this too long.

This is my DbContext:

```
using MySql.Data.Entity;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

namespace src.Database.Models
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class DefaultDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DefaultDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DefaultDbContext, MigrationConfiguration>());
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Character> Characters { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CharacterClothes> CharacterClothes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CharacterVehicles> CharacterVehicles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Dealership> Dealership { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DealershipVehicle> DealershipVehicles { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<DefaultDbContext>
    {
        private static string ConnectionString;

        public static void SetConnectionParameters(string serverAddress, string username, string password, string database, uint port = 3306)
        {
            var connectionStringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                Server = serverAddress,
                UserID = username,
                Password = password,
                Database = database,
                Port = port
            };

            ConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        private static DefaultDbContext _instance;

        public static DefaultDbContext Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance != null) return _instance;
                return _instance = new ContextFactory().Create();
            }
            private set { }
        }

        public DefaultDbContext Create()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnectionString)) throw new InvalidOperationException("Please set the connection parameters before trying to instantiate a database connection.");

            return new DefaultDbContext(ConnectionString);
        }
    }

    internal sealed class MigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DefaultDbContext>
    {
        public MigrationConfiguration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
        }
    }
}
```

So, it is using an instance for all connections which i access like this:

```
var user = ContextFactory.Instance.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
var dealerships = ContextFactory.Instance.Dealership.ToList();
```

And it is working fine!

Though, **occasionally** I get this error:

**There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.**

Which I suppose it's because it's trying to use the Instance while it's already in use.

I've been searching for days on how to fix it, but still i couldn't make it work. I've read about **MultipleActiveResultSets** but i'm using MySQL and it seems it isn't supported.

Comment: **NEVER** use a singleton for an Entity Framework DbContext. Not only Singleton is an anti-pattern, it's the worst you can do with EF.

Comment: I figured, is doing something like this okay? `using (var ctx = new ContextFactory().Create())
{
    // crud
}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change it

```
private static DefaultDbContext _instance;
```

to

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static DefaultDbContext _instance;
```

It could be better to create a new `DBContext` instance for per thread/request. Sharing same `DbContext` by threads is  dangerous and objectionable. It will be cause that different thread try to use same `DBContext` instance which it is being already used.

Also, there is a very good article [here](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/10/make-the-dbcontext-ambient-with-unitofworkscope/) about the **UnitOfWork, Transaction Management and benefits of creating the DbContext for per thread/request.**

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, you're right. I should refactor that and make a new per request, but this will do for now!